# making a query for stock/price trend in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cf6cb/4)

Table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE company
    (`company_id` int,`name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO company
    (`company_id`,`name`)
VALUES
    (1,"Company A"),
    (2,"Company B")

;

CREATE TABLE price
    (`company_id` int,`price` int,`time` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO price
    (`company_id`,`price`,`time`)
VALUES
    (1,50,'2015-02-21 02:34:40'),
    (2,60,'2015-02-21 02:35:40'),
    (1,70,'2015-02-21 05:34:40'),
    (2,120,'2015-02-21 05:35:40'),
    (1,150,'2015-02-22 02:34:40'),
    (2,130,'2015-02-22 02:35:40'),
    (1,170,'2015-02-22 05:34:40'),
    (2,190,'2015-02-22 05:35:40')
```

I'm using Cron Jobs to fetch company prices. In concatenating the price history for each company, how can I make sure that only the last one in each day is included? In this case, I want all of the price records around `05:30am` concatenated.

This is the result I'm trying to get (I have used Date(time) to only get the dates from the timestamps):

```
COMPANY_ID          PRICE            TIME
1                   70|170   2015-02-21|2015-02-22  
2                  120|190   2015-02-21|2015-02-22
```

I have tried the following query but it doesn't work. The prices don't correspond to the dates and I don't know how to exclude all of the `2:30 am` records before applying the `Group_concat` function.

```
SELECT company_id,price,trend_date FROM
   ( 
     SELECT  company_id, GROUP_CONCAT(price SEPARATOR'|') AS price,
     GROUP_CONCAT(trend_date SEPARATOR'|') AS trend_date
     FROM 
     (
       SELECT company_id,price,
              DATE(time) AS trend_date 
       FROM price
       ORDER BY time ASC
     )x1
     GROUP BY company_id
   )t1
```

Can anyone show me how to get the desired result?

Comment: This statement: `I want to make sure there is only one price point for each day for each company` makes it seem like you should be getting one row per company per price point, but you actually want just one row per company, right?, with the other data concatenated

Comment: @Lamak Yes, you are right. Just one row per company, with all of its price data concatenated in the `price field`

Comment: @RedGiant Please amend your question accordingly.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. What do you want?

Comment: you should better add unique `id` field in your `price` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this should work as intended:

```
SELECT  p.company_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(price SEPARATOR '|') as price,
        GROUP_CONCAT(PriceDate SEPARATOR '|') as trend_date
FROM price as p
INNER JOIN (SELECT  company_id,
                    DATE(`time`) as PriceDate,
                    MAX(`time`) as MaxTime
            FROM price
            GROUP BY company_id,
                     DATE(`time`)) as t
    ON p.company_id = t.company_id
    AND p.`time` = t.MaxTime
GROUP BY p.company_id
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cf6cb/9) the modified sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit unorthodox but I think it solves your problem:

```
 SELECT company_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(price SEPARATOR'|'), 
        GROUP_CONCAT(trend_date SEPARATOR'|')            
   FROM (
         SELECT *
            FROM ( 
                   SELECT company_id,
                          DATE(`time`) `trend_date`,
                          price
                     FROM price
                 ORDER BY `time` DESC
                 ) AS a
        GROUP BY company_id, `trend_date` 
        ) AS b
GROUP BY company_id
```